# ¿Cómo obtener un promedio de una base de datos cargada en Google Colab?

Tags: python

Trato de sacar el promedio de una columna de una base de datos que tiene edades con lo siguiente:

```
fh = open('/content/sample_data/casos_confirmados.csv', 'r')
from statistics import mean
next(fh)
for line in fh:
  casos=line.split(",")
  edad_promedio=int(casos.mean[3])
  print(edad_promedio)

fh.close()
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-39b8029b2f38> in <module>()
      4 for line in fh:
      5   casos=line.split(",")
----> 6   edad_promedio=int(casos.mean[3])
      7   print(edad_promedio)
      8 

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

cómo lo podría resolver?

Comment: Recomiendo el uso de pandas para trabajar con datos

Answer (score 1):

Una vez spliteada la linea, `casos` contiene una lista con los campos de esa linea. Sin embargo, estás accediendo a un atributo `mean` que no existe en un objeto `list`.

Suponiendo que el campo cuya media quieres calcular está en el índice `3`, deberías acceder al valor con `casos[3]` y, para calcular la media, almacenar cada uno de los datos en una lista que luego le pases a la función `mean`:

```
values = []
for line in fh:
    casos = line.split(',')
    values.append(int(casos[3])) # Guarda el dato de la linea en la lista values
edad_promedio = mean(values)
```

---

Por otro lado, como comenta [Christian](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/183782/christian), te puede resultar útil el uso de `pandas` para manejar datos y realizar múltiples tipos de cálculos.

```
import pandas as pd

# Suponiendo que tu archivo tiene una linea de cabecera, y la tercera columna se llama edad
data = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/casos_confirmados.csv')
edad_promedio = data.edad.mean()
```